# "the property or field has not been initialized" error while trying to add user to sharepoint group

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010

Finding "the property or field has not been initialized. It has not been requested or the request has not been executed. It may need to be explicitly requested." error when trying to add user to sharepoint group.
Here is the code:

```
string temp="r2\user"; //domain\user
User user = web.EnsureUser(temp);
using (ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(url))
{
Web web = clientContext.Web;
Group testingOwnersGroup = web.SiteGroups.GetById(grpId);
UserCollection collUser = testingOwnersGroup.Users;
collUser.AddUser(user);
clientContext.Load(user);
clientContext.Load(testingOwnersGroup);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
}
```

Please help me with this!!!

Comment: You have `User user = web.EnsureUser(temp)` on line 2, and then `Web web = clientContext.Web` inside the using statement. This may not fix this particular issue, but it'll solve a future one :)